# Can you add an 'abbr' tag in a SVG 'text' tag?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to add an `<abbr>` to an SVG's `<text>` tag, with an end result such as `<text><abbr title="Goals Per Match">GPM</abbr></text>`. I'm having no luck with it, so I was wondering if it was just my implementation or if it's just not possible with SVG.

Here's how I'm currently implementing it:

```
svg.append("text")
    .attr("id", "club_label")
    .attr("x", width / 2 + 5 )
    .attr("y", height )
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .append("abbr")
    .attr("title", "Goals Per Match")
    .text("GPM");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `<abbr>` element  in SVG.  Also, SVG doesn't support the `title` attribute.  It has a `<title>` element instead.

So the equivalent in SVG would be the following:

```css
text.abbr {
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="100" y="100" class="abbr">GPM<title>Goals Per Minute</title></text>
</svg>
```

Note that the `dotted` modifier for `text-decoration` doesn't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`<abbr>` element is an HTML element and not SVG element. These are two different sets of elements. You cannot mix them up. The complete list of SVG elements is in [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element).